# How can I eager load grandchild attribute in Hibernate and serialize accordingly

Tags: hibernate, jackson

I am new to Hibernate.

User has one to many relationship  with Address which has one to many relationship with checkpoint. Lazy load is enabled.

Hibernate Models:

```
public class user{
    long id;
    String name;
    Set<Address> addresses;
    //Getters and Stters
}

public class Address{
    long id;
    User user;
    String name;
    Set<Checkpoint> checkpoints;
    //Getters and Stters
}

public class Checkpoint{
    long id;
    Address address;
    String name;
    //Getters and Stters
}
```

Requirement is that sometimes i need to eager load only user and their address  and sometimes i need to eager load checkpoints of address as well.

Also the result needs to be to serialize to json accordingly.  Currently i am using JsonIgnore which doesn't serve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @JsonView annotation according to your needs:

```
// View definitions:
class Views {
    static class Public { }
    static class ExtendedPublic extends PublicView { }
    static class Internal extends ExtendedPublicView { }
}

public class User{

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)    
    long id;

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    String name;

    @JsonView(Views.ExtendedPublic.class)
    Set<Address> addresses;
    //Getters and Stters
}

public class Address{
    @JsonView(Views.ExtendedPublic.class)
    long id;

    @JsonView(Views.ExtendedPublic.class)
    User user;

    @JsonView(Views.ExtendedPublic.class)
    String name;

    @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
    Set<Checkpoint> checkpoints;
    //Getters and Stters
}

public class Checkpoint{
    @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
    long id;

    @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
    Address address;

    @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
    String name;
    //Getters and Stters
}

// prints only Views.Public.class annotated properties
objectMapper.writeValueUsingView(out, userInstance, Views.Public.class);

// prints Views.Public.class + Views.ExtendedPublic.class annotated properties
objectMapper.writeValueUsingView(out, userInstance, Views.ExtendedPublic.class);

// prints Views.Public.class + Views.ExtendedPublic.class + Views.Internal.class annotated properties
objectMapper.writeValueUsingView(out, userInstance, Views.Internal.class);
```